# How to store the number without the comma in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

We have a web application which from the UI is passing a value say 50.00 but when it is stored in the database it is stored as 50000. Most of our installations are for English OS (windows 7) but this problem is on a dutch installation.

Is there a way I can tweak SQL server so that it saves the value at 50 and not 50000 without changing any code? The field in the database is an integer.

The customer has SQL server 2008 express.

Comment: Are you storing the number as text? Otherwise it doesn't really have a decimal separator, that's just something handled by the client / application for UI.

Comment: The most sensible way is to translate, in the application, from a *string* into a more appropriate data type (e.g. `int`, `decimal`, `double`, whatever fits). Then pass that across to SQL Server as a *parameter* of the same type.

Comment: @JamesZ : The number is stored as an integer. I have just looked at the database and it is stored as 50000 and not 50.

Comment: Without changing any code?  I highly doubt it.

Comment: If the field is an `integer`, why on earth is a *string* like `50.00` getting anywhere near it? Your code is broken, so seeking a solution that doesn't change any code would be a band-aid at best.

Comment: Its may be because when you are passing the value to e.g store proc parameter you are passing as string although when you save in DB save as Integer as data type in DB is integer, so i will suggest to check in which formate you are passing the value to DB from your application.